# catkin_make problem after several workspace directory

Tags: ros, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I have one problem with catkin. When I have just installed ROS I made catkin_ws folder. After it I tried to download source from git and I noticed that with this package from git there is readme file with installation steps. So I made another workspace. I mean I got two workspace:

- catkin_ws just after instalation
  (there was only one package - beginners tutorial)
- tum_simulator_ws
  with two packages.

I read [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) that if we really don't need several workspace we should avoid this situation, because there are some complications.

So I remove catkin_ws, but now I can't use catkin_make.
Please help me.

```
przemek@przem:~/tum_simulator_ws/src$ catkin_init_workspace 
Creating symlink "/home/przemek/tum_simulator_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
przemek@przem:~/tum_simulator_ws/src$ cd ~/tum_simulator_ws/
przemek@przem:~/tum_simulator_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/przemek/tum_simulator_ws
Source space: /home/przemek/tum_simulator_ws/src
The specified base path "/home/przemek/tum_simulator_ws" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace
przemek@przem:~/tum_simulator_ws$
```

I use ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.
In my .bashrc file I have this lines:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:~/tum_simulator_ws

LC_NUMERIC=C
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196927/catkin_make--problem-after-several-workspace-directory/) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

do this for sourcing `.bashrc`, i dont know if your sourcing is similar or not, but this is how i did....writing for ur case

> source ~/tum_simulator_ws/devel/setup.bash

plus did you reset the terminal for matkin_make in directory, if so,
do a `source devel/setup.bash` or edit `.bashrc` like above

---

Originally posted by [Nouman Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/20072/nouman-tahir/) with karma: 35 on 2014-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0